# How to remove curly quotes?

Tags: python

In my utf-8 encoded file, there are curly quotes (“”).

How do I replace them all with normal quotes (")?

```
cell_info.replace('“','"')
cell_info.replace('”','"')
```

did not work. No error message.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Which encoding should we declare at the top of our file for this to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`str.replace()` doesn't replace the original string, it just returns a new one.

Do:

```
cell_info = cell_info.replace('“','"').replace('”','"')
```

Comment: Note that you may also need to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file just below your version of `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 6):

other way that work with my code is this:

```
cell_info = cell_info.replace(u'\u201c', '"').replace(u'\u201d', '"')
```

this because i already have this `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of my script

Answer (score 0):

```
cell_info = cell_info.replace('“','"').replace('”','"')
```

The *replace* method return a new string with the replacement done. It doesn't act directly on the string.