# How to check if a dict's member is equal to a string in Jinja2

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 Template that I am serving in flask that looks somthing like this:

```
{% if current_user.UserType == “Admin” %}
Stuff
{% endif %}
```

However I am getting an error like this

```
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'\u201c' at 860
```

What is the proper way to check a key's value in Jinja2?

Comment: I think you're doing it correctly, the problem looks like those [fancy/curly quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428876/how-to-remove-curly-quotes) around `“Admin”`; see [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 34: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264892/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-u201c-in-position-3)

Comment: You're right, thanks for some reason Jekyll was converting the quotes to the fancy ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was the one downshift mentioned with encoding, I was under the impression that it was somthing to do with the jinja2 syntax but,

```
{% if current_user.UserType == "Admin" %}
Stuff
{% endif %}
```

works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use bracket notation:

```
{% if current_user["UserType"] == “Admin” %}
Stuff
{% endif %}
```

Or the `get` method:

```
{% if current_user.get("UserType") == “Admin” %}
Stuff
{% endif %}
```

Also use [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jinja%20dictionary%20access&*)